# View the adapter starting from a certain position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView displaying a list of images & and when a user clicks on one of the images e.g position 2, it takes them to a ViewPager with that same position & they can horizontally swipe to view other images from there.

The issue I am having is how to get that specific position & call `instantiateItem` programmatically since on swiping, the user sees the same image.

**My code**

**RecyclerView Adapter** (should pass the position clicked to the ViewPager adapter)

```
public static int catPositionToView;
onBindViewHolder(...){
   holder.recylerviewItem.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        catPositionToView = position; //catPosition is a global static variable so that I can access it directly in the viewpager adaper

    //I then launch the next activity which has a viewpager
    context.startActivity(...)
   }
}
```

**ViewPager Adapter**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(myList.get(catPositionToView).getImage()) //Issue is here
            .into(myImageView);
}
```

I can view the image of the passed position but how do I view other positions from there sequentially?

Comment: Did you tried using  View Pager set Current Item method?

Comment: Getting the specific position is your logic we do not know how your data is Connected . if data is same the just use `pager.setCurrentItem` with position  and it should work ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way may help you

**in Recyclerview Adapter**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,ViewPagerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("currentPosition",your recyclerview click position);         
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**in ViewpagerActivity**

```
currentItemPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("currentPosition",0);
List<Image> myList;// = new ArrayList<>();//your list on pager adapter activity
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(myList));
viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItemPosition);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(myList.size());
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        List imagelist;
        public ImageAdapter(List<Image> imagelist) {
            this.imagelist = imagelist;
            //mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imagelist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
            return view == ((Imageiew) object);//LinearLayout or your layout root view
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imagelist.get(position).getImage()) //Issue is here//. now check here
                    .into(myImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((ImageView)object);
        }
    }
```

if you want to update manually or swipe
to save last position from page change listener or on which page you have for help to get back on previous page like

```
currentItemPosition = last position;
viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItemPosition);
```

to update for specified position

Comment: Thanks. I was overthinking. setCurrentItem method was never on my mind